# Swift: downloadTaskWithURL sometimes "succeeds" with non-nil location even though file does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

The `downloadTaskWithURL` function sometimes returns a non-nil location for a file that does not exist.

There is no file at `http://192.168.0.102:3000/p/1461224691.mp4` in the test environment.

Most of the time, invoking `downloadTaskWithURL` on this URL results in the expected error message:

> Error downloading message during network operation. Download URL:
>   http://192.168.0.102:3000/p/1461224691.mp4. Location: nil. Error:
>   Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL
>   was not found on this server." UserInfo=0x17547b640
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.0.102:3000/p/1461224691.mp4,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this
>   server.,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.0.102:3000/p/1461224691.mp4})

Occasionally, and in a non-deterministic way, `downloadTaskWithURL` believes the file exists and writes something to the `location` variable. As a result, the guard condition does not fail, and the code continues to execute ... which it should not.

The permanent file created by `fileManager.moveItemAtURL(location!, toURL: fileURL)` is only 1 byte, confirming that the network file never existed in the first place.

Why does `downloadTaskWithURL` behave like this?

```
func download() {
    // Verify <networkURL>
    guard let downloadURL = NSURL(string: networkURL) where !networkURL.isEmpty else {
        print("Error downloading message: invalid download URL. URL: \(networkURL)")
        return
    }

    // Generate filename for storing locally
    let suffix = (networkURL as NSString).pathExtension
    let localFilename = getUniqueFilename("." + suffix)

    // Create download request
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(downloadURL) { location, response, error in
        guard location != nil && error == nil else {
            print("Error downloading message during network operation. Download URL: \(downloadURL). Location: \(location). Error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        // If here, no errors so save message to permanent location
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        do {
            let documents = try fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
            let fileURL = documents.URLByAppendingPathComponent(localFilename)
            try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(location!, toURL: fileURL)
            self.doFileDownloaded(fileURL, localFilename: localFilename)
            print("Downloaded file @ \(localFilename). Download URL: \(downloadURL)")
        } catch {
            print("Error downloading message during save operation. Network URL: \(self.networkURL). Filename: \(localFilename). Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    // Start download
    print("Starting download @ \(downloadURL)")
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, the server is returning a 404, but the download task is returning a basically-empty file?  And you're certain that the server actually returned an error code (by verifying the server logs)?

Either way, I would suggest checking the status code in the response object.  If it isn't a 200, then the download task probably just downloaded the response body of an error page.  Or, if the status code is 0, the connection timed out.  Either way, treat it as a failure.

You might also try forcing this to all happen on a single thread and see if the nondeterminism goes away.

Comment: thanks, good ideas. will try them out and report the results!